# getting the inner corner angle

Tags: triangles

I have four points that make concave quad:

[image: concave quadrilateral]

now I wanna get the inner angle of the (b) corner in degrees.
note: the inner angle is greater than 180 degree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join b-d splitting the angle into 2 parts.

Part 1:
Using Cosine Rule:
$$\cos(\theta_1)=\dfrac{ad^2-ab^2-bd^2}{2\times ab\times bd}$$

Similarly:
$$\cos(\theta_1)=\dfrac{cd^2-bc^2-bd^2}{2\times bc\times bd}$$

Comment: thank you very much, your idea as more useful because i don't wanna to ignore d point

Comment: @MoHaKa:  whatever you want, but paying attention to $d$ distracts from the problem at hand and doubles the work.

Comment: i realized that, but if i ignored (d) point I won't be able to determine where is the inner corner, isn't that?

Comment: @MoHaKa:  you gave us the coordinates.  But if you mean looking at the shape of the quadrilateral to see which corner is concave, you are right.

Comment: yep, i meant that, anyway thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

Draw $ac$ and use the law of cosines at $\angle b$, then subtract from $360$

$226=68+50-2\sqrt{50\cdot 68} \cos \theta \\ \cos \theta\approx -0.926 \\ \theta \approx 157.83 \\ \text{Your angle } \approx 202.17$

Comment: Your approach is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha$ be the angle from $bc$ to $ba$ then
$$\tan \alpha=\frac{m_2-m_1}{1+m_1m_2}$$
where $m_1$ is the inclination of $bc$ and $m_2$ is the inclination of $ba$.

$m_1=\frac{10-9}{18-11}=\frac{1}{7}$

$m_2=\frac{9-11}{11-3}=-\frac{1}{4}$

you want to find $360^o-\alpha$.

**Edit:**
With a calculator:

$\alpha=202.17^o$